# How to restrict routes in spring security dynamically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Good day,

I am using spring security to restrict user, and i am using mongodb.

I have created UserDetail and userDetail Services.

her is my webSecurity config.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService mongoUserDetails() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(mongoUserDetails());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/static/unsecure/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }

}
```

I am storing permissions in database like this.

```
"permissions" : [
    "/reports/report1", 
    "/reports/report2"
]
```

and here is userDetail service.

```
public class MongoUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;
    private final boolean enabled;

    public MongoUserDetails(String username, String password, String[] authorities, boolean isEnabled) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.grantedAuthorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(authorities);
        this.enabled = isEnabled;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }
}
```

in private final List grantedAuthorities; I have successfully stored authorites. which are "/reports/report1", "/reports/report2"

When i run my web application it is redirecting my to login page and after   valid credentials it redirects my to /hello page.

Now i am creating controllers and actions like

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/user/greeting")
    public String greeting(HttpServletRequest request){
        return "welcome secure";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login1")
    public String greeting1(HttpServletRequest request){

    }

}
```

so since List grantedAuthorities; does not contains this route it should not allowed the user for this action

how can i achieve this. assuming all authorities are dynamic.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example:
Authentication service:

```
@Service
public class AuthService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserJpaRepository userJpaRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserProfileJPARepository profileJPARepository;
    @Autowired
    private UserProfileContainer profileContainer;

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = (User) userJpaRepository.findByLogin(username);
        GrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name());
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) new SecureUser(
                user.getId(),
                user.getFirstName(),
                user.getLastName(),
                user.getEmail(),
                user.getMobileNumber(),
                user.getLogin(),
                user.getPassword(),
                user.isActive(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                Arrays.asList(authority)
        );
        user.setLastLogonTime(new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime()));
        userJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
        profileContainer.setUser(user);
        return userDetails;
    }

}
```

Session scoped bean:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class UserProfileContainer {
    private User user = null;

    public UserProfileContainer() {
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

And in User class you cal store a `List<String> allowedURLS = new ArrayList<>();`

**AFTER EDIT:**

I've wrote this example. In this case I have some SecureUser.class which extends `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` and in this class I have `Set<String> allowedPathSet` actually HashSet. And here is the custom filter:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomerFilter implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // nothing here...
  }

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

    SecurityContextImpl sci = (SecurityContextImpl) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
    if (sci != null) {
      SecureUser user = (SecureUser) sci.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
      String url = req.getRequestURI();
      if (!user.path.contains("url")) ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("http://redirect-URL-Here/");
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {

  }
}
```

This example isn't a silver bullet but the main idea is present here and it work.

Comment: you mean i have to check for permission in every controller?

Comment: Yes. Or you can actually write your own filter which will make it automatically.

Comment: can you please also help me how to use custom filters?

Comment: looks like that will solve my problem, but i can see number of classes by name Filter can you please provide me the qualified name of this Filter class??

Comment: `javax.servlet.Filter` be careful this filter will handle all requests to your app.

Comment: got it. i applied your code but after and in the doFilter method i am getting nullpointerexception at this line. MongoUserDetails userDetails = (MongoUserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

Comment: looks like this filter is working before authentication while i would like to activate this filter only after successfull login. can you please also help me in this i am very close.

Comment: `if (userDetails != null){ /* validate user rights here*/}` And yes, as I sad, this filter will handle all request and unauthenticated too.

Comment: Great that solved my problem. you are great help buddy.

Comment: you are great. can i reach you when need more help on spring ??

Comment: you can try. :)

Comment: are you on linkedin?

Comment: sent you connect request :)

Comment: hey, this filter is also working for static content can you please tell me how to ignore static content

Comment: use String matchers