# How to change HttpSecurity without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

we have library for authentication that is defined by company as core component. This package defines WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and HttpSecurity chain. Is there any way how to affect the chain after the application is initialized? We need to add some path that does not require authentication at all.

Thank you,
Martin

Comment: maybe [this](http://itshrine.com/dynamically-secure-methods-by-spring-security/) can help you. Or maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49631550/7546121) answer is more suited for you.

Answer (score -3):

If it uses java to configure the HttpSecurity chain, it should be possible to extend this class, call super.configure(HttpSecurity http) and then add your custom pathes

Comment: I am afraid this is not the case. There is a brutal logic with conditional beans and I never know whitch component is used to and to be "overwritten".